# Why does my Netbeans not highlight undefined variables in PHP/Javascript, but does in Java?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

I am just starting to use Netbeans (NetBeans IDE 7.4 (Build 201310111528)). It took a long time to set up but I cannot for the life of me figure out why undefined variables don't get highlighted for PHP and Javascript. I went under options>hints> Language:PHP, and made sure Unitialized Variables was checked off, and Show As:Warning (Check Variable initalized by reference was off). Some errors get properly highlighted while the undefined variables get nothing. Here's an example with a simple program:

```
<?php

$b=$g+$g; //no error
$a=$sadfhasdf8adhfieiofwffsd; //no error

; //empty statement error
a=a; //syntax error
?>
```

The weird thing is that if I switch to Java, everything works:

```
public class JavaApplication2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int a=22;
   int b= a*c; //cannot find symbol "c" correctly working
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how it works in Netbeans 7.4 and 8.0 Beta:

```
<?php
// Example 1
$foo = $bar;  // DOES NOT give "Variable $bar seems to be uninitialized" error.

// Example 2 
function do_something_function () {
    $foo = $bar;  // Gives "Variable $bar seems to be uninitialized" error.
}

// Example 3
class foo {
    public static function do_something_method () {
        $foo = $bar;  // Gives "Variable $bar seems to be uninitialized" error.
    }
}
?>
```

In other words, it will flag the error within a function or method (examples 2 and 3), but not within the global space (example 1).

This is the behavior with Netbeans 7.4 and 8.0 Beta -- but I don't think that's always been the case. I'm not sure when it switched. I've been using Netbeans for years and only recently noticed that it works like this now.

Comment: I'm a little late, but thank you very much for your help! Wish I could give you upvote, but too new at stackoverflow too